# Keyboard shortcuts don't work for migration path list

Tags: bug, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts

This used to work, but I can't select a migration path anymore with the number keys. Usually, you could press <kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>6</kbd> to select the custom field.

[image]

Comment: Btw, why can I see "50 votes remaining" if you are a mod there...

Comment: I can close as many questions as I like—the number never decreases :)

Comment: So maybe you should write a feature request to remove this useless number :D

Comment: Aren't you confusing this with the [SO Close Voters](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) keyboard shortcut [userscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts)? On that screen btw I can select G, I, R, and S...

Comment: @rene No, I'm using the built-in shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, our built-in keyboard shortcuts script didn't support that popup pane, since it has a different HTML markup than others.

A fix is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.3.11.3167` on meta, `2015.3.11.2379` on sites).