# Keyboard shortcuts don't work properly for destroying accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, keyboard-shortcuts

While destroying a throw-away account used by a spammer on Ask Different, I noticed that the keyboard shortcuts are *almost* working:

<kbd>M</kbd> -> <kbd>M</kbd> -> <kbd>4</kbd> brings you to the following menu. According to the hints, I should now be able to press <kbd>A</kbd> to select the first radio button, but instead it focuses on the text area meant for additional information.

I couldn't find other input dialogs with a text area on the same level as radio buttons, but that's probably something the [keyboard shortcut generator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251029/295232) cannot deal with.

[image]

Comment: You can hit tab to move focus away from the textarea then the "A/B" will work, I'm not sure there's another way around it other than not auto-focusing the textarea (which would be best IMO, not sure how often that textarea is used though)

Comment: I destroy spam accounts all the time. I usually just M -> M -> 4 -> Tab -> A.

Comment: Thanks Cai and Oded, Tab works for me. I still think the text area shouldn't be auto-focused, as I doubt it's the most common option. That makes this question halfway between a [bug] and a [feature-request].

Comment: Somehow this reminds me of IDDQD...

Comment: @Oded FYI, with [this userscript](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/raw/master/destroy-spammer/destroy-spammer.user.js) I can do it in two clicks. As a precaution, it activates only if the user has 1-4 deleted posts and no non-deleted posts. Now I'm off to https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/spammers/site?site=44

Comment: Tested and confirmed it works. Though... if its due to a redesign of the page...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed with the roll-out of the [new mod-menu design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332324); it now works as expected. Thank you Brian!

Comment: So the headline *Cat on keyboard destroys SE community* can become reality?

Comment: The cat may destroy the community, but it can [never destroy Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312308/295232)...

Comment: I don't think you linked the correct answer in your comment.

Comment: @mathlander when I wrote that comment, nobody tried to destroy the Community user yet (and many users, even moderators, don't know there's a difference anyway).