# Is it possible for a mod to delete the community user?

Tags: discussion, moderators, community-user

A mod can delete a user, or destroy their account if the user has less than 500 reputation points.

The community user has 1 reputation point and is a user. So, what happens if I try to delete or destroy the community user of our site? Are there safeguards for this since deleting the community user can break the entire site?

Comment: There is a way to find out ... we only need a mod brave enough to test it ...

Comment: The community user doesn't exist, it's just a constant in a file: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user#comment351111_19739

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, it still does have a profile page... so it's non trivial.

Comment: Walking into the thread excited to see what's inside but instead seeing people experimentally trying to delete the Community user feels like https://media1.giphy.com/media/ZFzpCzdWotBIdiYoLA/giphy.gif

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it's not possible. I can fill in a form specifying the reason for deletion, but upon submitting I get a 500 Internal Server Error page:

> #### Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

Comment: Specifying reason: *Hasta la vista, baby*?

Comment: Nope, "for science".

Comment: TFW a mod actually attempts to delete them to test....

Comment: I wasn't expecting that.

Comment: Hope you braced yourself for the revenge in case your test would have been successful... ;-)

Comment: I wonder what happens when you try to delete your *own* account? Just kidding. I wouldn't try that one. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford that's not possible, you have to contact the Community Team for certain actions on your own account.

Comment: Have you tried the above? Since you mentioned _"can"_, I'm not sure if it's theory.

Comment: Yes I tried; this what I get after clicking the Submit button.

Comment: @Glorfindel I hope you are not joking, going to test it now :P

Comment: It had been funny if it would be successful. ;-)

Comment: @peterh Then everyone would see 500 a lot more...

Answer (score 13):

While [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312308/241919) is about deleting the Community user, trying to *destroy* it gives a different error message:

> #### Moderator action failed
>
> ---
>
> User -1 cannot be destroyed because they are a moderator or an employee.
> Users who are moderators or employees can only be destroyed by a developer or community team member.
> The Stack Exchange community team has been notified.

[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV7QM.png)

Comment: *The Stack Exchange community team has been notified.* Cue a "wtf are you doing" message from a CM in your site's mod chat :-)

Comment: "The Stack Exchange community team has been notified." I get a strong `sudo` vibe from this.

Comment: Now let's see what happens if you try to suspend or de-mod it...

Comment: @Anonymous the official meta post about that says “The process will be initiated by a formal request from one or more moderators on a site, sent privately via an email to community@stackexchange.com.” So community might just say “I’d rather not get de-modded today” :P

Comment: @EkadhSingh But what if, theoretically, they accepted it?

Comment: @Anonymous now *that* would be interesting. Somebody should try it.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Yeah... and better add a note on the status page saying "may be down or completely messed up, sorry in advance if everyone's account is deleted".

Comment: I am curious, what would happen if an employee would try to delete it.

Comment: @Anonymous ask a question asking “what would happen if you de-mod community” and some moderator will probably try it out... (also explain why it isnt a duplicate of this question)

Comment: @EkadhSingh Can't, question banned.